# Concatenar duas colunas de uma matriz formando uma string de caracteres

Tags: r, matriz

Suponha que possuo os seguintes vetores:

```
n <- c(1:5)
c <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
```

Construo a seguinte matriz com eles:

```
m <- matrix(c(n,c), ncol = 2)
```

Qual a melhor forma para obter uma vetor assim:

```
"1 - A", "2 - B", "3 - C", "4 - D", "5 - E"
```

sem fazer loop (for/while)?

Posso utilizar o comando

```
vetor <- paste(m[1,1], m[1,2], sep = " - ")
```

mas apenas o primeiro elemento é criado:

```
"1 - A"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tua resposta está quase lá. Em vez de selecionar apenas uma linha da matriz, com o comando

```
paste(m[1, 1], m[1, 2], sep = " - ")
```

selecione todas ao mesmo tempo:

```
paste(m[, 1], m[, 2], sep = " - ")
[1] "1 - A" "2 - B" "3 - C" "4 - D" "5 - E"
```

De toda forma, sequer era necessário criar a matriz `m`. O `R` consegue trabalhar diretamente com os vetores `n` e `c`:

```
paste(n, c, sep = " - ")
[1] "1 - A" "2 - B" "3 - C" "4 - D" "5 - E"
```